# Informix Native Driver for Delphi XE2 Professional?

Tags: delphi, informix, delphi-xe2

please does exist some native driver for Informix databases for Delphi XE2 Professional ?
What are you using?

I know that does exist IDAC, now opensource, but these sources are for pre-Unicode Delphi versions and is not easy to change it (at least for me).

Thank you very much.

Comment: Informix is so little used, I think you're going to have to port it yourself. I doubt it will be hard. Mostly change all PChar to PAnsiChar, and you'll be 99% done.

Comment: @Warren P: it is not so easy but with some small troubles it is working (at least after first tests). Some time ago I tried it with replacement of string/ansistring too and it was bad way. Thanks.

Comment: @user1238056: How would the project owner do if he has to port IDAC to XE2?

Answer (score 1):

I also used IDAC before, but with upgrading to XE2 I changed to [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com).